# THREE.js - How to have different colored particles?

Tags: three.js

I basically have a bunch of particles that were created by THREE.Points with a THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial.

Currently they all have the same color (based on the material).

**Question:**
How can I get different colors particles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `THREE.Geometry()` inside your `THREE.Points()` and If you only have a few number of colors you want to use you can create separate materials and separate your points based on which color you want to assign them. Example at: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_random.html

If you are using `THREE.BufferGeometry()` inside your `THREE.Points()` you can assign a different color to each of your points using only one `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`. Example at: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_points.html